# Is it possible to configure a new domain on linux using PHP code?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to dynamically create a new website for my clients based on the domain they enter. I wonder if it is possible to:

1. Take the new domain name through an input
2. Add a new domain to the dns service (bind or tinydns)
3. Add new virtual host to apache

I guess for number 3 I could use http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html and that also help to avoid restaring Apache service. I'm not sure how I should use or even could use PHP to do all these? Maybe I could do shell_exec and run a bashscript?

Please point me to some direction for further research.

Comment: What 'domains' are you speaking about? Do you mean subdomains? Real top level domains (TLD) have to be officially registered.

Comment: @ComFreek yup I do understal that TLD must be purchased and pointed to the nameservers. Here we assume that all that is already taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point could be performed with some code like

```
<?php
$domain = "";
if (array_key_exists("domain", $_POST)) {
    $domain = $_POST["domain"]; /* You should validate the input before assigning it! */
} else {
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
    <label for="domain">Domain name:</label><input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

For the second point, there exists a tool named nsupdate. [This howto](http://caunter.ca/nsupdate.txt) provides some tips for that program. Please note that, according to [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nsupdate&oldid=539763181), nsupdate is supported only by BIND 8 and later.

For the third point, the method you mentioned is a possible solution. It has the advantage of not being required to run the script with the permissions needed to change a server configuration file, just the permission needed to create a directory at some location you can choose.

Comment: Interesting, I think I also found something for tinydns here: http://qmail.jms1.net/djbdns/dyndns.shtml Have you every used tinydns instead of bind? Some websites are touting it as the replacement for bind